# ImportError: No module named local

Tags: django, python-2.7, traceback

I'm trying to run the file `manage.py`, whose code is below

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'config.settings.local')
try:
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
except ImportError:
    # The above import may fail for some other reason. Ensure that the
    # issue is really that Django is missing to avoid masking other
    # exceptions on Python 2.
    try:
        import django  # noqa
    except ImportError:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        )
    raise

# This allows easy placement of apps within the interior
# myproject directory.
current_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(current_path, 'myproject'))

execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

with the following command:

```
python manage.py runserver_plus 0.0.0.0:8000
```

But I'm getting the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 29, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 308, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 110, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named local
```

I don't know how to interpret this traceback to fix the error. Can you please help?

Comment: You don't have any local.py file in the settings directory. It depend on your settings structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you've provided, and the error message, my best guess is that the module path provided for `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` is wrong: `config.settings.local`.

For this path to be valid, you would need a directory structure like the following:

```
/
├── manage.py
├── config/
|   ├── __init__.py
|   ├── settings/
|   |   ├── __init__.py
|   |   ├── local.py
```

Is that what your project structure looks like (including `__init__.py` files)? If not, either modify your directory structure, or modify the value of `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`.